# Using SQLAlchemy, I want to eagerly join a parent's children when the parent is loaded, but not join if there are no children

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have some simple tables in PostgreSQL and my models defined like this:

```
class Parent(Base):
    children = relationship('Child', backref='parent', innerjoin=True, lazy='joined')
class Child(Base):
    pass
```

Where Child has an FK called parent_id that points to the Parent.

When I load a parent, I want its children to be loaded immediately with a join statement, which is what this definition is doing.

However, when there are no children for a parent, no parents are loaded with a statement like:

```
parent = session.query(Parent).get(parent_id)
parent == None
```

Raw SQL + SQLAlchemy:

```
>>> for i in session.execute('select id from parents limit 1'):
    print i
(147194, )
>>> p = session.query(Parent).get(147194)
>>> p == None
True
>>> c = Child()
>>> c.parent_id = 147194
>>> session.add(c)
>>> session.commit()
>>> p = session.query(Parent).get(147194)
>>> p == None
False
```

Answer (score 0):

I found you can specify the kind of load dynamically by using `sqlalchemy.orm.lazyload`

```
>>> session.query(Parent).options(lazyload('children')).get(147195) == None
False
```